# CSV Reader programmin formatting

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to format the csv reader to come out in that way:
1. somestuff, somestuff2, somestuff3
unfortunately the numbers are wrapping up at the top of the table instead of in beginning of the line. any help?

```
    <?php
        $row = 1;
        $handle = fopen("random.csv", "r");
        $number = 1;
        echo("<table>");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            echo($number . "." . " " . "<tr>\r\n");
            foreach ($data as $index=>$val) {

                echo("\t<td>$val</td>\r\n");
            }
            echo("</tr>\r\n");
            $numer ++;
        }
        echo("</table>");
        fclose($handle);
    ?>
```

Comment: Numbers should be inside `<td>` and not where you like them to be.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new cell for those numbers:

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen("random.csv", "r");
    $number = 1;
    echo '
    <table>';
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo '
      <tr>
        <td>' . $number . '.</td>';

        foreach ($data as $index => $val) {
            echo '
        <td>' . $val . '</td>';
        }
        echo '
      </tr>';
        $number ++;
    }
    echo '
    </table>';
    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: It is still on the top.